# MS Chart: How can you change the color of each label on the Axis of a Bar Chart?

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, bar-chart

I have a bar chart which shows different categories on the Y axis.

I can change the color of all of them on the axis at the same time by using:

```
 chart.ChartAreas["MyChart"].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = "Red";
```

However it doesn't allow me to set the color for each of them.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok The only solution I have found is to create a custom label and set the color that way:

```
this._chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(new CustomLabel(position - 1, position + 1, point.AxisLabel, 0, LabelMarkStyle.None));

this._chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels[position - 1].ForeColor = GetColor(point.AxisLabel);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try adding custom labels to the chart, and that will allow you to modify each one individually.

```
private void AddCustomLabelAtYValue(double YValue, string Text, Color ForeColor)
{
    double scale = chart.ChartAreas["MyChart"].AxisY.Maximum - 
        chart.ChartAreas["MyChart"].AxisY.Minimum;
    double offset = scale * 0.5;
    CustomLabel customLabel = new CustomLabel(YValue - offset, 
        YValue + offset, Text, 0, LabelMarkStyle.None);
    customLabel.ForeColor = ForeColor;
    chart.ChartAreas["MyChart"].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(customLabel);
}
```