# how can I change forecolor of a chart label?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, label

how can i change the fore color of the chart labels? here's a screenshot of the chart
[image]

i tried using the chart1.series[0].FontForeColor = color.white; but the entire chart turns white.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9641090/2186128 I think this thread is simmilar. Look into that.

Comment: the values in my chart is dynamic and i don't really have enough time to rebuild my chart. i was hoping to find something that i can directly use without starting over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
        this.chart1.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;

        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LineColor = Color.Red;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineColor = Color.Red;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Red;
        this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Here `LabelStyle.ForeColor` changes the label color, as you requested.

The properties `LineColor` and `MajorGrid.LineColor` allow modification of the grid lines (black on your screenshot), in case you need that as well. The colors Red and AliceBlue, of course, are just for example.